# <a> link takes form fields and then redirects

Tags: php, forms

I have a simple form field with two form fields. Then below the two fields I have a button that's rendered with the `<a>` property. This `<a>` button redirects to another URL with a larger form. I want this `<a>` button to take the two form fields and somehow place it in the url.

Kind of like

```
<a href='http://siteurl.com/zipcode=.$_POST['zipcode'].'>BUTTON</a>
```

Is this possible? And what should I look into?

---

I figured out a way to do it the way I want.

Posting it here for people with the same question, and also recommendations on my method and if there is a better/simpler way of doing it.

```
<script>
$('#submit_form').click(function(){
    var url_beg = 'http://SITEURL/sellermoredetails.aspx?siteName=Great%202%20Be%20Home&siteUrl=SellProbates.com&redirectUrl=http://www.SITEURL.com&Zip='
    var zipcode = $('input[name="zipcode"]').val();
    var url_post_zip = '&BuyerType='
    var buyer = $('select[name="buyer"]').val();
    var url_post_buyer = '&Email='
    var email = $('input[name="email"]').val();
    var url_post_email = '&CaseId=4845868&SiteId=54048&buyerid=0'

    $('#submit_form').attr('href', url_beg + zipcode + url_post_zip + buyer + url_post_buyer + email + url_post_email).val();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Use a get method and then get the value

Comment: I tried that. I changed the form to method='get' then I set the href to "http://siteurl.com/zipcode='.$_GET['zipcode'].'" it didn't work. It basically cut off the url right after zipcode=

Comment: Why can't you just use a `<button>` or `<input>` instead of an `<a>` to submit the form? That's what forms are for.

Comment: in your form method use get Or use jquery to  get the values and then generate a link

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use the GET method by putting params in the url that you're linking to

```
echo '<a href="http://siteurl.com/?zipcode=' . $_POST['zipcode'] . '">BUTTON</a>';
```

The format for mutliple params is like so:

```
http://myurl.com?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3...
```

Comment: So this works when both the form fields and the <a> link are on the same page?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take a form field and place it in the url of `<a>` you can use javascript instead:

```
var link=document.getElementById("link");
var input=document.getElementById("textbox");
link.onclick=function(){
  window.location.href = "http://siteurl.com/zipcode="+input.value;
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/He9w4/

Answer (score 0):

You can use session. Use a submit button instand of "a" tag, and when the form submit store values into session and redirect to the bigger form url

```
if (isset($_POST['SUBMIT']) {
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['Field1'] = $_POST['Field1'];
   $_SESSION['Field2'] = $_POST['Field2'];
   echo "<script>window.location='bigger_form.php'</script>";
   //Or redirect with header() :D
}
```